# I want integrate the firebase custom model in flutter app. how i integrate?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I don't know where to save my ML model in Firebase

See the below code and get this an error :

> Failed assertion: line 259 pos 12: 'remoteModelName != null ||
>   localModelName != null': is not true.

This is the void of on pressed:

```
Future runmodel() async {

    manager.registerLocalModelSource(FirebaseLocalModelSource(
    modelName: 'mobilenet_v10',
    assetFilePath: 'assets/mobilenet_v2.tflite'));

    var imageBytes = (await rootBundle.load('assets/download.jpg')).buffer;
    img.Image image = img.decodeJpg(imageBytes.asUint8List());
    image = img.copyResize(image, height: 224, width: 224);

    var results = await interpreter.run();

    print(results);}
```

Comment: Can you include some example code and/or images?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yes i can upload images, and i upload my attempts

Answer (score 0):

After registering the local model to the manager, be sure to define the localModelName for the interpreter as well.

```
   await interpreter.run(
      localModelName: modelName,
      inputOutputOptions: io, 
      inputBytes: bytes
    );
```

Hope this helps.